# django celery upgrade from 2.5 to 3.0.19 - tasks pending

Tags: upgrade, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to upgrade our celery from 2.5 to 3.0.19 (using django-celery) but have this strange issue.

I updated the `/etc/default` files and used the new `/etc/init.d/celeryd` scripts, I see that the celery workers (as well as celerybeat) are running fine.

However, the tasks I'm launching using `delay` seem to always stay in `PENDING` state, and my celery workers don't appear to receive any new tasks.

RabbitMQ is running, and I've updated the `BROKER_URL` and it looks correct. I'm not getting any errors otherwise.

Any ideas what to look for or how to debug this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Celery tasks dont finish and constantly remain pending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482197/django-celery-tasks-dont-finish-and-constantly-remain-pending)